# How to handle search queries that contain "/" in Ember.js apps?

Tags: ember.js

I created a small app that takes a search query and returns mock content. You can see the app here: http://embersherpa.com/wip/search-example/app/#/search

It work correctly when entering the query via the search but not via the url.

**How do I correctly handle search queries with "/" when entered via url?**

Comment: What would you consider to be the correct handling of such queries?

Comment: That's a good question. I suppose, the same as when entering via the search field. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not put your keyword directly into the URL. Instead escape it first with `encodeURIComponent` and unescape it with `decodeURIComponent` in your model hook. The rough code look like this:

```
serialize : function(model){
  // model is the keyword in your case
  return {keyword: encodeURIComponent(model)};
},
model : function(params){
  var keyword = decodeURIComponent(params.keyword);
  // do what you need to do with the keyword
}
```

Comment: This only impacts how keywords are passed between routes which is not a problem. (I think) the problem lies in how the Router handles the parameters.

Comment: Believe me. You insert an "/" as plain character into the URL and if you look into the console, you will see a `Assertion failed: The URL '/search//' did match any routes in your application`. So do proper escaping and unescaping and it will work.

Comment: serialize method does not get hit in Ember 2.1